# Is "noch selten" correct?

Tags: adverbial

I will start with an example sentence:

> So gut war es noch selten.

I have only seen "noch selten" used with "nur" like this:

> So gut ist es nur noch selten.

Which expresses that something used to be good, but is only rarely good anymore.

Duden Grammar p.907 lists "noch" as an adverbial of time to add to negation words:

> So gut war es noch nie.

This sounds correct. Is "selten" even usable in this way? Can "noch" modify a free-standing (as in, not with "nur" for example) adverbial of frequency like "selten" is (hopefully?)?

I have considered it may be a modal particle, however I have not found what it would add as modal particle that it would not add as an adverb.

Answer (score 4):

It's correct, although I have never encountered it in spoken language. You probably find it mostly in literary texts.

Duden gives an example:

> So eine Frechheit ist mir noch selten vorgekommen.
> ([vorkommen
> 1b](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorkommen))

Second example:

[image]